# JQDatePicker not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 3 user controls. Each of them has one JQDatePicker, in my text.aspx page I have these 3 user controls and a ScriptManager. When I run the project I can just see the textbox part of DatePickers, and the Picker button does not show itself. What's wrong?

```
 <%@ Register assembly="JQControls" namespace="JQControls" tagprefix="JQControls2" %>

 <JQControls2:JQDatePicker ID="dtpTahatorDate" runat="server" 
            ChangeMonth="True" ChangeYear="True"
                        DateFormat="YMD" IEDateFormat="YMD" Regional="fa"
            ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <JQControls2:JQLoader ID="jqLoader2" Theme="Humanity" runat="server" />
```

[image] this button does not apper when I run the project.

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: Need more information's, did you get any javascript error ? what is the home page of this control. Only magician can find an error on the code you show here (not that there are not magician between us) - but please help us, help you.

Comment: Can the downvoter pleaaaaaase tell me what have I done wrong? So that I can make it right at least :)

Comment: no error. I just don't see the button.

Comment: Now you need to tell us what JQControls is. If it is your library you should show us JQDatePicker source code.

Comment: Actually I'm working on someone else's project and I'm not sure whose control it is, but I'm sure it's not pur guys control :) is should be in the JQuery library I suppose.

Comment: jQuery library is pure JavaScript, here you have ASP.NET WebForms control - it is custom code and without knowledge how it looks like we will not be able to help you beside our best effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why and I don't know what's the logic behind this, but the problem was that I should have put the JQLoader before (or upper in code lines) JQDatePicher control. This solved my problem so I decided to answer my question maybe it helps someone who is stuck in the same case. If anyone has any points about such linear behaviour please add here.

```
<JQControls2:JQLoader ID="jqLoader2" Theme="Humanity" runat="server" />
<JQControls2:JQDatePicker ID="dtpTahatorDate" runat="server" 
        ChangeMonth="True" ChangeYear="True"
        DateFormat="YMD" IEDateFormat="YMD" Regional="fa"
        ShowSelectButton="True" />
```